# Exercise 2.C.14 - Linear Algebra Done Right

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

**Question:** Suppose $U_1, \cdots, U_m$ are finite dimensional subspaces of $V$. Prove that $U_1 + \cdots + U_m$ is finite dimensional, and that $\dim(U_1 + \cdots + U_m) \leq \dim U_1 + \cdots + \dim U_m$.

**My solution:** I attempted an induction proof with the identity $\dim(A + B) = \dim A + \dim B - \dim (A \cap B)$.

Clearly $\dim A \leq \dim A$. Then hypothesize that $\dim(U_1 + \cdots + U_m) \leq \dim U_1 + \cdots + \dim U_m$.

Add $U_{m+1}$ to both sides and use the identity and inductive hypothesis:

\begin{align}
\dim(U_1 + \cdots + U_m + U_{m+1}) 
&= \dim(U_1 + \cdots + U_m) + \dim U_{m+1} \\&\hspace{2cm}- \dim((U_1 + \cdots+ U_m) \cap U_{m+1}) \\ &\leq \dim(U_1 + \cdots+ U_m) + \dim U_{m+1} \\&\leq \dim U_1 + \cdots + \dim U_{m+1}
\end{align}

I'm just looking for a solution verification because the solution manual lists a completely different answer.

Comment: Other than your sloppy "Add $U_{m+1}$ to both sides," it looks fine to me. I suspect they gave (and wanted) a far less sophisticated argument; the identity you are using is a nontrivial result.

Comment: It suffices that you rely on $\dim(A+B)\le \dim A+\dim B$ while performing the induction argument.